# D3js Contour Displaying as Black Box

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have been largely unsuccessful in getting a d3 contour to work by following [this example on observable](https://observablehq.com/@d3/volcano-contours) at a single elevation. My code ends up just displaying a black box.

[image: Result of D3 Contour]

My attempt at generating the contour can be seen below. I also put it [here in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcohen/pqxo1w9j/18/) with the elevation data from the observable example.

```
var data = {"width": ..., "height":..., "values": ...} 
var svg = d3.select('#container')
    .append('svg')

var width = data.width;
var height = data.height;

const path = d3.geoPath();
const contours = d3.contours().size([width, height]);

const g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.03);

g.append("path")
    .attr("d", path(contours.contour(data.values, [90])));
```

This d3-contour library has been pretty non-intuitive to me, so I may be way off in how I should be approaching this. What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you're setting the thresholds incorrectly.

Right now your threshold array has just one value:

```
.attr("d", path(contours.contour(data.values, [90])));
```

Thus, you have just one path (if you inspect your SVG you'll see it). If you look at that Observable you'll see that Bostock is creating several paths inside a loop, with different threshold values.

Let's fix it properly setting several thresholds, the many thresholds you have the many paths you'll create. I manually set some of them, from 95 to 140:

```
const contours = d3.contours().size([width, height])
  .thresholds([95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140]);
```

Then, just use a basic enter selection to create the paths:

```
g.selectAll(null)
  .data(contours(data.values))
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path);
```

Finally, don't forget to set the fill of the paths, otherwise it will be all black.

And here is your code with those changes:

```js
data = {
  "width": 87,
  "height": 61,
  "values": [103, 104, 104, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 106, 106, 105, 105, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 107, 107, 106, 105, 105, 107, 108, 109, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 108, 107, 107, 107, 107, 106, 106, 105, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 103, 103, 103, 103, 102, 102, 101, 101, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 99, 98, 97, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 104, 104, 105, 105, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 108, 108, 108, 106, 106, 108, 109, 110, 110, 112, 112, 113, 112, 111, 110, 110, 110, 110, 109, 109, 109, 108, 107, 107, 107, 107, 106, 106, 105, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 103, 103, 103, 103, 102, 102, 101, 101, 100, 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 97, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 104, 105, 105, 106, 106, 107, 107, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 113, 115, 116, 115, 113, 112, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 109, 108, 108, 108, 108, 107, 106, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 104, 104, 104, 104, 103, 103, 103, 102, 102, 102, 101, 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 97, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 105, 105, 106, 106, 107, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 112, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116, 117, 119, 118, 117, 116, 114, 113, 112, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 109, 109, 108, 107, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 105, 105, 105, 104, 104, 104, 103, 103, 103, 102, 102, 102, 101, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 97, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 105, 106, 106, 107, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 114, 115, 116, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 122, 123, 124, 124, 123, 121, 119, 118, 117, 115, 114, 112, 111, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 109, 109, 108, 109, 107, 107, 106, 106, 105, 105, 104, 104, 104, 104, 103, 103, 102, 102, 102, 101, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 111, 111, 112, 113, 112, 111, 111, 112, 115, 118, 118, 119, 126, 128, 128, 127, 128, 128, 129, 130, 129, 128, 127, 125, 122, 120, 118, 117, 115, 114, 112, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 110, 110, 110, 109, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 105, 105, 104, 104, 104, 103, 103, 102, 102, 102, 101, 100, 99, 99, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 106, 107, 107, 108, 108, 108, 109, 110, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 114, 115, 116, 116, 119, 123, 125, 130, 133, 134, 134, 134, 134, 135, 135, 136, 135, 134, 132, 130, 128, 124, 121, 119, 118, 116, 114, 112, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 111, 110, 110, 110, 109, 108, 108, 107, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 104, 104, 103, 103, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 99, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 94, 94, 94, 94, 107, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 117, 120, 120, 121, 123, 129, 134, 136, 138, 139, 139, 139, 140, 142, 142, 141, 141, 140, 137, 134, 131, 127, 124, 122, 120, 118, 117, 115, 113, 114, 113, 114, 114, 113, 112, 111, 110, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 105, 105, 104, 104, 104, 103, 103, 103, 101, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 94, 94, 94, 94, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 121, 125, 125, 127, 131, 136, 140, 141, 142, 144, 144, 145, 148, 149, 148, 147, 146, 144, 140, 138, 136, 130, 127, 125, 123, 121, 119, 118, 117, 117, 116, 116, 116, 115, 114, 113, 113, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 105, 103, 103, 102, 102, 102, 103, 101, 100, 100, 100, 99, 98, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 94, 94, 94, 107, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 113, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 123, 126, 129, 131, 134, 139, 142, 144, 145, 147, 148, 150, 152, 154, 154, 153, 154, 151, 149, 146, 143, 140, 136, 130, 128, 126, 124, 122, 121, 120, 119, 118, 117, 117, 117, 116, 116, 115, 113, 112, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 101, 100, 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 94, 94, 94, 107, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 112, 115, 117, 119, 122, 125, 127, 130, 133, 137, 141, 143, 145, 148, 149, 152, 155, 157, 159, 160, 160, 161, 162, 159, 156, 153, 149, 146, 142, 139, 134, 130, 128, 126, 125, 122, 120, 120, 120, 119, 119, 119, 118, 117, 115, 113, 111, 110, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 106, 105, 104, 104, 103, 102, 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 95, 94, 94, 108, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 112, 115, 118, 121, 125, 128, 131, 134, 138, 141, 145, 147, 149, 152, 157, 160, 161, 163, 166, 169, 170, 170, 171, 168, 162, 158, 155, 152, 148, 144, 140, 136, 132, 129, 127, 124, 122, 121, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 119, 117, 115, 113, 110, 110, 110, 110, 109, 108, 108, 107, 107, 106, 105, 104, 102, 100, 100, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 94, 94, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 111, 112, 114, 117, 120, 124, 128, 131, 135, 138, 142, 145, 149, 152, 155, 158, 163, 166, 167, 170, 173, 175, 175, 175, 173, 171, 169, 164, 160, 156, 153, 149, 144, 140, 136, 131, 129, 126, 124, 123, 123, 122, 121, 120, 120, 120, 119, 117, 115, 111, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 109, 109, 110, 109, 108, 106, 103, 101, 100, 100, 100, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 95, 94, 108, 109, 110, 110, 110, 113, 114, 116, 119, 122, 126, 131, 134, 138, 141, 145, 149, 152, 156, 160, 164, 169, 171, 174, 177, 175, 178, 179, 177, 175, 174, 172, 168, 163, 160, 157, 151, 147, 143, 138, 133, 130, 128, 125, 125, 124, 123, 122, 121, 121, 120, 120, 118, 116, 115, 111, 110, 110, 110, 110, 113, 114, 113, 112, 110, 107, 105, 102, 100, 100, 100, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 94, 108, 109, 110, 110, 112, 115, 116, 118, 122, 125, 129, 133, 137, 140, 144, 149, 152, 157, 161, 165, 169, 173, 176, 179, 179, 180, 180, 180, 178, 178, 176, 175, 171, 165, 163, 160, 153, 148, 143, 139, 135, 132, 129, 128, 127, 125, 124, 124, 123, 123, 122, 122, 120, 118, 117, 118, 115, 117, 118, 118, 119, 117, 116, 115, 112, 109, 107, 105, 100, 100, 100, 100, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 95, 108, 109, 110, 111, 114, 116, 118, 122, 127, 130, 133, 136, 140, 144, 148, 153, 157, 161, 165, 169, 173, 177, 180, 180, 180, 180, 181, 180, 180, 180, 179, 178, 173, 168, 165, 161, 156, 149, 143, 139, 136, 133, 130, 129, 128, 126, 126, 125, 125, 125, 125, 124, 122, 121, 120, 120, 120, 120, 121, 122, 123, 122, 120, 117, 114, 111, 108, 106, 105, 100, 100, 100, 100, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 95, 107, 108, 110, 113, 115, 118, 121, 126, 131, 134, 137, 140, 143, 148, 152, 157, 162, 165, 169, 173, 177, 181, 181, 181, 180, 181, 181, 181, 180, 180, 180, 178, 176, 170, 167, 163, 158, 152, 145, 140, 137, 134, 132, 130, 129, 127, 127, 126, 127, 128, 128, 126, 125, 125, 125, 123, 126, 128, 129, 130, 130, 125, 124, 119, 116, 114, 112, 110, 107, 106, 105, 100, 100, 100, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 95, 107, 109, 111, 116, 119, 122, 125, 130, 135, 137, 140, 144, 148, 152, 156, 161, 165, 168, 172, 177, 181, 184, 181, 181, 181, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 178, 178, 173, 168, 163, 158, 152, 146, 141, 138, 136, 134, 132, 130, 129, 128, 128, 130, 130, 130, 129, 128, 129, 129, 130, 132, 133, 133, 134, 134, 132, 128, 122, 119, 116, 114, 112, 108, 106, 105, 105, 100, 100, 100, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 95, 108, 110, 112, 117, 122, 126, 129, 135, 139, 141, 144, 149, 153, 156, 160, 165, 168, 171, 177, 181, 184, 185, 182, 180, 180, 179, 178, 178, 180, 179, 179, 178, 176, 173, 168, 163, 157, 152, 148, 143, 139, 137, 135, 133, 131, 130, 130, 131, 132, 132, 132, 131, 132, 132, 133, 134, 136, 137, 137, 137, 136, 134, 131, 124, 121, 118, 116, 114, 111, 109, 107, 106, 105, 100, 100, 100, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 96, 96, 96, 96, 108, 110, 114, 120, 126, 129, 134, 139, 142, 144, 146, 152, 158, 161, 164, 168, 171, 175, 181, 184, 186, 186, 183, 179, 178, 178, 177, 175, 178, 177, 177, 176, 175, 173, 168, 162, 156, 153, 149, 145, 142, 140, 138, 136, 133, 132, 132, 132, 134, 134, 134, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 140, 140, 140, 140, 139, 137, 133, 127, 123, 120, 118, 115, 112, 108, 108, 106, 106, 105, 100, 100, 100, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 97, 96, 96, 96, 108, 110, 116, 122, 128, 133, 137, 141, 143, 146, 149, 154, 161, 165, 168, 172, 175, 180, 184, 188, 189, 187, 182, 178, 176, 176, 175, 173, 174, 173, 175, 174, 173, 171, 168, 161, 157, 154, 150, 148, 145, 143, 141, 138, 135, 135, 134, 135, 135, 136, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 139, 135, 130, 126, 123, 120, 117, 114, 111, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 98, 98, 98, 97, 97, 96, 110, 112, 118, 124, 130, 135, 139, 142, 145, 148, 151, 157, 163, 169, 172, 176, 179, 183, 187, 190, 190, 186, 180, 177, 175, 173, 170, 169, 169, 170, 171, 172, 170, 170, 167, 163, 160, 157, 154, 152, 149, 147, 144, 140, 137, 137, 136, 137, 138, 138, 139, 140, 141, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 138, 134, 131, 128, 124, 121, 118, 115, 112, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 99, 98, 98, 98, 97, 97, 110, 114, 120, 126, 131, 136, 140, 143, 146, 149, 154, 159, 166, 171, 177, 180, 182, 186, 190, 190, 190, 185, 179, 174, 171, 168, 166, 163, 164, 163, 166, 169, 170, 170, 168, 164, 162, 161, 158, 155, 153, 150, 147, 143, 139, 139, 139, 139, 140, 141, 141, 142, 142, 141, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 137, 134, 131, 128, 125, 122, 119, 116, 114, 112, 110, 109, 109, 108, 107, 105, 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 99, 98, 98, 97, 97, 110, 115, 121, 127, 132, 136, 140, 144, 148, 151, 157, 162, 169, 174, 178, 181, 186, 188, 190, 191, 190, 184, 177, 172, 168, 165, 162, 159, 158, 158, 159, 161, 166, 167, 169, 166, 164, 163, 161, 159, 156, 153, 149, 146, 142, 142, 141, 142, 143, 143, 143, 143, 144, 142, 141, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 138, 134, 131, 128, 125, 123, 120, 117, 116, 114, 112, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 102, 101, 100, 99, 99, 99, 98, 98, 97, 110, 116, 121, 127, 132, 136, 140, 144, 148, 154, 160, 166, 171, 176, 180, 184, 189, 190, 191, 191, 191, 183, 176, 170, 166, 163, 159, 156, 154, 155, 155, 158, 161, 165, 170, 167, 166, 165, 163, 161, 158, 155, 152, 150, 146, 145, 145, 145, 146, 146, 144, 145, 145, 144, 142, 141, 140, 140, 140, 140, 138, 136, 134, 131, 128, 125, 123, 121, 119, 117, 115, 113, 112, 111, 111, 110, 108, 106, 105, 102, 100, 100, 99, 99, 99, 98, 98, 110, 114, 119, 126, 131, 135, 140, 144, 149, 158, 164, 168, 172, 176, 183, 184, 189, 190, 191, 191, 190, 183, 174, 169, 165, 161, 158, 154, 150, 151, 152, 155, 159, 164, 168, 168, 168, 167, 165, 163, 160, 158, 155, 153, 150, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 147, 146, 146, 145, 143, 142, 141, 140, 139, 138, 136, 134, 132, 131, 128, 126, 124, 122, 120, 118, 116, 114, 113, 113, 112, 111, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 102, 100, 99, 99, 99, 99, 110, 113, 119, 125, 131, 136, 141, 145, 150, 158, 164, 168, 172, 177, 183, 187, 189, 191, 192, 191, 190, 183, 174, 168, 164, 160, 157, 153, 150, 149, 150, 154, 158, 162, 166, 170, 170, 168, 166, 164, 162, 160, 158, 155, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 149, 148, 147, 146, 145, 143, 142, 140, 139, 137, 135, 134, 132, 131, 129, 127, 125, 123, 121, 119, 117, 116, 114, 114, 113, 112, 110, 108, 107, 105, 103, 100, 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 110, 112, 118, 124, 130, 136, 142, 146, 151, 157, 163, 168, 174, 178, 183, 187, 189, 190, 191, 192, 189, 182, 174, 168, 164, 160, 157, 153, 149, 148, 149, 153, 157, 161, 167, 170, 170, 170, 168, 166, 165, 163, 159, 156, 154, 153, 155, 155, 155, 155, 152, 150, 149, 147, 145, 143, 141, 140, 139, 138, 136, 134, 133, 131, 130, 128, 126, 124, 122, 120, 119, 117, 116, 115, 114, 113, 111, 110, 107, 106, 105, 105, 102, 101, 100, 100, 100, 110, 111, 116, 122, 129, 137, 142, 146, 151, 158, 164, 168, 172, 179, 183, 186, 189, 190, 192, 193, 188, 182, 174, 168, 164, 161, 157, 154, 151, 149, 151, 154, 158, 161, 167, 170, 170, 170, 170, 169, 168, 166, 160, 157, 156, 156, 157, 158, 159, 159, 156, 153, 150, 148, 146, 144, 141, 140, 140, 138, 136, 135, 134, 133, 131, 129, 127, 125, 123, 122, 120, 118, 117, 116, 115, 114, 112, 111, 110, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 102, 100, 100, 108, 110, 115, 121, 131, 137, 142, 147, 152, 159, 163, 167, 170, 177, 182, 184, 187, 189, 192, 194, 189, 183, 174, 169, 165, 161, 158, 156, 154, 153, 154, 157, 160, 164, 167, 171, 172, 174, 174, 173, 171, 168, 161, 159, 158, 158, 159, 161, 161, 160, 158, 155, 151, 149, 147, 144, 142, 141, 140, 138, 137, 136, 135, 134, 132, 130, 128, 126, 125, 123, 121, 119, 118, 117, 116, 115, 113, 112, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 105, 101, 100, 108, 110, 114, 120, 128, 134, 140, 146, 152, 158, 162, 166, 169, 175, 180, 183, 186, 189, 193, 195, 190, 184, 176, 171, 167, 163, 160, 158, 157, 156, 157, 159, 163, 166, 170, 174, 176, 178, 178, 176, 172, 167, 164, 161, 161, 160, 161, 163, 163, 163, 160, 157, 153, 150, 148, 146, 144, 142, 141, 140, 139, 138, 136, 135, 134, 133, 129, 127, 126, 124, 122, 121, 119, 118, 117, 116, 114, 113, 112, 111, 110, 110, 109, 109, 107, 104, 100, 107, 110, 115, 119, 123, 129, 135, 141, 146, 156, 161, 165, 168, 173, 179, 182, 186, 189, 193, 194, 191, 184, 179, 175, 170, 166, 162, 161, 160, 160, 161, 162, 165, 169, 172, 176, 178, 179, 179, 176, 172, 168, 165, 163, 163, 163, 163, 165, 166, 164, 161, 158, 155, 152, 150, 147, 146, 144, 143, 142, 141, 139, 139, 138, 137, 135, 131, 128, 127, 125, 124, 122, 121, 119, 118, 116, 115, 113, 112, 111, 111, 110, 110, 109, 109, 105, 100, 107, 110, 114, 117, 121, 126, 130, 135, 142, 151, 159, 163, 167, 171, 177, 182, 185, 189, 192, 193, 191, 187, 183, 179, 174, 169, 167, 166, 164, 164, 165, 166, 169, 171, 174, 178, 179, 180, 180, 178, 173, 169, 166, 165, 165, 166, 165, 168, 169, 166, 163, 159, 157, 154, 152, 149, 148, 147, 146, 145, 143, 142, 141, 140, 139, 138, 133, 130, 128, 127, 125, 124, 122, 120, 118, 117, 115, 112, 111, 111, 111, 111, 110, 109, 108, 106, 100, 107, 109, 113, 118, 122, 126, 129, 134, 139, 150, 156, 160, 165, 170, 175, 181, 184, 188, 191, 192, 192, 189, 185, 181, 177, 173, 171, 169, 168, 167, 169, 170, 172, 174, 176, 178, 179, 180, 180, 179, 175, 170, 168, 166, 166, 168, 168, 170, 170, 168, 164, 160, 158, 155, 152, 151, 150, 149, 149, 148, 147, 145, 144, 143, 142, 141, 136, 133, 130, 129, 127, 125, 123, 120, 119, 118, 115, 112, 111, 111, 111, 110, 109, 109, 109, 105, 100, 105, 107, 111, 117, 121, 124, 127, 131, 137, 148, 154, 159, 164, 168, 174, 181, 184, 187, 190, 191, 191, 190, 187, 184, 180, 178, 175, 174, 172, 171, 173, 173, 173, 176, 178, 179, 180, 180, 180, 179, 175, 170, 168, 166, 168, 169, 170, 170, 170, 170, 166, 161, 158, 156, 154, 153, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 148, 147, 146, 145, 143, 139, 135, 133, 131, 129, 126, 124, 121, 120, 118, 114, 111, 111, 111, 110, 110, 109, 107, 106, 104, 100, 104, 106, 110, 114, 118, 121, 125, 129, 135, 142, 150, 157, 162, 167, 173, 180, 183, 186, 188, 190, 190, 190, 189, 184, 183, 181, 180, 179, 179, 176, 177, 176, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 180, 179, 177, 173, 169, 167, 166, 167, 169, 170, 170, 170, 170, 167, 161, 159, 157, 155, 153, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 149, 147, 145, 141, 138, 135, 133, 130, 127, 125, 123, 121, 118, 113, 111, 110, 110, 109, 109, 107, 106, 105, 103, 100, 104, 106, 108, 111, 115, 119, 123, 128, 134, 141, 148, 154, 161, 166, 172, 179, 182, 184, 186, 189, 190, 190, 190, 187, 185, 183, 180, 180, 180, 179, 179, 177, 176, 177, 178, 178, 178, 177, 176, 174, 171, 168, 166, 164, 166, 168, 170, 170, 170, 170, 168, 162, 159, 157, 155, 153, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 148, 144, 140, 137, 134, 132, 129, 127, 125, 122, 117, 111, 110, 107, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 103, 105, 107, 110, 114, 118, 122, 127, 132, 140, 146, 153, 159, 165, 171, 176, 180, 183, 185, 186, 189, 190, 188, 187, 184, 182, 180, 180, 180, 179, 178, 176, 176, 176, 176, 174, 174, 173, 172, 170, 168, 167, 165, 163, 164, 165, 169, 170, 170, 170, 166, 162, 159, 157, 155, 153, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 146, 142, 139, 136, 133, 131, 128, 125, 122, 117, 110, 108, 106, 105, 104, 103, 103, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 103, 106, 108, 112, 116, 121, 125, 130, 138, 145, 151, 157, 163, 170, 174, 178, 181, 181, 184, 186, 186, 187, 186, 184, 181, 180, 180, 180, 179, 178, 174, 173, 173, 171, 170, 170, 169, 168, 167, 166, 164, 163, 162, 161, 164, 167, 169, 170, 168, 164, 160, 158, 157, 155, 153, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 147, 144, 141, 138, 135, 133, 128, 125, 122, 116, 109, 107, 104, 104, 103, 102, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 105, 107, 110, 115, 120, 124, 129, 136, 143, 149, 155, 162, 168, 170, 174, 176, 178, 179, 181, 182, 184, 184, 183, 181, 180, 180, 179, 177, 174, 172, 170, 168, 166, 165, 164, 164, 164, 164, 162, 160, 159, 159, 158, 160, 162, 164, 166, 166, 163, 159, 157, 156, 155, 153, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 149, 146, 143, 140, 137, 133, 129, 124, 119, 112, 108, 105, 103, 103, 102, 101, 101, 101, 101, 100, 100, 101, 102, 104, 106, 109, 113, 118, 122, 127, 133, 141, 149, 155, 161, 165, 168, 170, 172, 175, 176, 177, 179, 181, 181, 181, 180, 180, 179, 177, 174, 171, 167, 165, 163, 161, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 157, 155, 155, 154, 154, 155, 157, 159, 161, 161, 161, 159, 156, 154, 154, 153, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 149, 147, 144, 141, 137, 133, 129, 123, 116, 110, 107, 104, 102, 102, 101, 101, 101, 100, 100, 100, 100, 102, 103, 104, 106, 108, 112, 116, 120, 125, 129, 137, 146, 154, 161, 163, 165, 166, 169, 172, 173, 174, 175, 177, 178, 178, 178, 178, 177, 174, 171, 168, 164, 160, 158, 157, 157, 156, 156, 156, 155, 152, 151, 150, 150, 151, 151, 152, 154, 156, 157, 157, 156, 155, 153, 152, 152, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 147, 144, 141, 138, 133, 127, 120, 113, 109, 106, 103, 101, 101, 101, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 110, 114, 118, 123, 127, 133, 143, 150, 156, 160, 160, 161, 162, 167, 170, 171, 172, 173, 175, 175, 174, 174, 173, 171, 168, 164, 160, 156, 155, 154, 153, 153, 152, 152, 150, 149, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 149, 149, 150, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 149, 147, 144, 141, 138, 132, 125, 118, 111, 108, 105, 103, 102, 101, 101, 101, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 110, 113, 117, 120, 125, 129, 138, 145, 151, 156, 156, 157, 158, 160, 164, 166, 168, 170, 171, 172, 171, 171, 169, 166, 163, 160, 156, 153, 151, 150, 150, 149, 149, 149, 148, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 147, 148, 148, 149, 149, 149, 148, 148, 148, 148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 148, 146, 143, 141, 136, 129, 123, 117, 110, 108, 105, 104, 103, 102, 102, 101, 101, 100, 100, 100, 100, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 109, 111, 115, 118, 122, 127, 133, 140, 143, 150, 152, 153, 155, 157, 159, 162, 164, 167, 168, 168, 168, 167, 166, 163, 160, 157, 153, 150, 148, 148, 147, 147, 147, 145, 145, 144, 143, 143, 143, 144, 144, 144, 144, 145, 145, 145, 145, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 147, 147, 148, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 149, 147, 145, 143, 141, 134, 127, 123, 117, 111, 108, 105, 105, 104, 104, 103, 103, 102, 101, 100, 100, 100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 109, 113, 116, 120, 125, 129, 133, 137, 143, 147, 149, 151, 152, 154, 158, 161, 164, 165, 164, 164, 163, 163, 160, 157, 154, 151, 149, 147, 145, 145, 144, 143, 141, 140, 141, 141, 141, 141, 141, 142, 142, 142, 142, 142, 142, 142, 143, 143, 143, 144, 144, 145, 146, 146, 146, 147, 148, 148, 148, 148, 145, 143, 142, 140, 134, 128, 123, 117, 112, 108, 106, 105, 105, 104, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 100, 99, 102, 103, 104, 105, 105, 106, 108, 110, 113, 118, 123, 127, 129, 132, 137, 141, 142, 142, 145, 150, 154, 157, 161, 161, 160, 160, 160, 159, 157, 154, 151, 148, 146, 145, 143, 142, 142, 139, 137, 136, 137, 137, 138, 138, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 140, 140, 141, 142, 142, 143, 144, 144, 144, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 144, 142, 140, 139, 136, 129, 124, 119, 113, 109, 106, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 101, 100, 99, 99, 102, 103, 104, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 111, 116, 121, 124, 126, 128, 131, 134, 135, 137, 139, 143, 147, 152, 156, 157, 157, 157, 156, 155, 153, 151, 148, 146, 143, 142, 141, 140, 138, 135, 133, 132, 132, 133, 133, 133, 134, 135, 135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 137, 137, 138, 138, 139, 140, 141, 141, 142, 142, 143, 142, 142, 141, 141, 140, 139, 137, 134, 133, 129, 125, 121, 114, 110, 107, 106, 106, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 99, 99, 102, 103, 104, 104, 105, 105, 106, 108, 110, 113, 118, 121, 124, 126, 128, 130, 132, 134, 136, 139, 143, 147, 150, 154, 154, 154, 153, 151, 149, 148, 146, 143, 141, 139, 137, 136, 132, 130, 128, 128, 128, 129, 129, 130, 130, 131, 132, 132, 132, 133, 134, 134, 135, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 139, 140, 140, 140, 139, 139, 138, 137, 137, 135, 132, 130, 129, 127, 124, 120, 116, 112, 109, 106, 105, 103, 102, 101, 101, 100, 99, 99, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 110, 114, 119, 121, 124, 126, 128, 129, 132, 134, 137, 140, 143, 147, 149, 151, 151, 151, 149, 147, 145, 143, 141, 138, 136, 134, 131, 128, 126, 124, 125, 125, 126, 126, 127, 128, 128, 129, 129, 130, 130, 131, 131, 132, 132, 133, 134, 135, 135, 136, 136, 137, 137, 136, 136, 135, 134, 133, 131, 129, 128, 127, 126, 123, 119, 115, 111, 109, 107, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 100, 100, 99, 101, 102, 103, 103, 104, 104, 105, 106, 108, 110, 112, 116, 119, 121, 124, 125, 127, 130, 132, 135, 137, 140, 143, 147, 149, 149, 149, 147, 145, 143, 141, 139, 136, 133, 131, 128, 125, 122, 121, 122, 122, 122, 123, 125, 125, 126, 127, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 129, 129, 130, 131, 131, 132, 132, 133, 133, 133, 132, 132, 131, 131, 130, 129, 128, 126, 125, 124, 121, 117, 111, 109, 108, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 101, 100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 102, 103, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 110, 114, 117, 119, 121, 123, 126, 128, 130, 133, 136, 139, 141, 144, 146, 147, 146, 145, 143, 141, 138, 136, 133, 130, 127, 124, 121, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 124, 125, 125, 126, 126, 125, 126, 126, 126, 125, 126, 127, 128, 128, 129, 129, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 126, 125, 123, 122, 119, 114, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 103, 102, 102, 101, 100, 100, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 112, 115, 117, 120, 122, 125, 127, 130, 132, 135, 137, 139, 142, 144, 144, 144, 142, 140, 138, 136, 132, 129, 126, 123, 120, 120, 119, 119, 118, 119, 119, 120, 120, 120, 121, 122, 122, 123, 123, 123, 123, 122, 123, 122, 122, 121, 122, 122, 122, 123, 123, 123, 124, 125, 125, 126, 126, 125, 124, 122, 120, 116, 113, 109, 107, 106, 105, 104, 104, 103, 102, 102, 101, 101, 100, 100, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 112, 114, 117, 119, 122, 124, 127, 129, 131, 134, 136, 138, 140, 142, 142, 142, 140, 138, 136, 133, 129, 125, 122, 120, 119, 118, 118, 117, 116, 117, 117, 118, 119, 119, 120, 120, 120, 121, 121, 121, 122, 121, 120, 120, 120, 119, 119, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 123, 123, 124, 124, 124, 123, 121, 119, 114, 112, 108, 106, 106, 104, 104, 103, 102, 102, 101, 101, 100, 100, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 113, 114, 116, 119, 121, 124, 126, 128, 130, 133, 135, 137, 138, 140, 140, 139, 137, 135, 133, 131, 127, 122, 120, 118, 118, 117, 117, 116, 115, 116, 116, 117, 118, 118, 118, 119, 119, 120, 120, 121, 121, 120, 119, 119, 118, 117, 117, 118, 119, 118, 118, 118, 119, 120, 122, 123, 123, 123, 122, 120, 117, 113, 110, 108, 106, 105, 104, 103, 103, 102, 101, 101, 100, 100, 99, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 111, 113, 115, 118, 121, 123, 125, 127, 129, 131, 133, 135, 137, 138, 138, 137, 134, 132, 130, 127, 122, 120, 118, 116, 116, 116, 116, 115, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 117, 118, 118, 119, 119, 119, 120, 120, 119, 118, 117, 117, 116, 116, 117, 117, 117, 118, 119, 119, 119, 120, 121, 121, 121, 121, 119, 116, 113, 110, 107, 105, 105, 103, 103, 103, 102, 101, 100, 100, 99, 99, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 116, 117, 120, 122, 124, 126, 129, 130, 132, 133, 135, 136, 136, 134, 132, 129, 126, 122, 120, 118, 116, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 113, 113, 114, 115, 116, 116, 117, 117, 117, 118, 118, 119, 119, 118, 117, 116, 116, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 117, 117, 118, 118, 119, 120, 120, 120, 120, 119, 116, 113, 109, 106, 104, 104, 103, 102, 102, 101, 101, 100, 99, 99, 99, 98, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 113, 115, 117, 117, 118, 121, 123, 126, 128, 130, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 131, 129, 125, 122, 120, 118, 116, 114, 113, 112, 112, 113, 112, 112, 111, 112, 113, 113, 114, 115, 116, 116, 117, 117, 118, 118, 116, 116, 115, 115, 115, 114, 114, 115, 116, 116, 117, 117, 118, 118, 119, 119, 120, 120, 117, 115, 112, 108, 106, 104, 103, 102, 102, 102, 101, 100, 99, 99, 99, 98, 98, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 113, 115, 117, 118, 120, 122, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 131, 128, 125, 121, 120, 118, 116, 114, 113, 113, 111, 111, 111, 111, 110, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 113, 114, 115, 115, 116, 117, 117, 116, 115, 114, 114, 113, 113, 114, 114, 115, 115, 116, 116, 117, 118, 118, 119, 119, 118, 116, 114, 112, 108, 105, 103, 103, 102, 101, 101, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 98, 97, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 110, 111, 113, 115, 118, 120, 121, 122, 124, 125, 125, 126, 127, 128, 127, 124, 121, 120, 118, 116, 114, 113, 112, 112, 110, 109, 109, 108, 108, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 112, 113, 114, 114, 115, 116, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 112, 113, 113, 114, 114, 115, 115, 116, 116, 117, 117, 118, 118, 117, 115, 113, 111, 107, 105, 103, 102, 101, 101, 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 98, 97, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 110, 111, 114, 116, 118, 120, 120, 121, 122, 122, 123, 124, 123, 123, 120, 118, 117, 115, 114, 115, 113, 111, 110, 109, 108, 108, 107, 107, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 111, 112, 113, 113, 114, 115, 115, 114, 113, 112, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 113, 114, 114, 115, 115, 116, 116, 117, 117, 116, 114, 112, 109, 106, 104, 102, 101, 100, 100, 99, 99, 99, 99, 98, 98, 97, 97]
}


var svg = d3.select('#container')
  .append('svg');

var width = data.width;
var height = data.height;

const path = d3.geoPath();
const contours = d3.contours().size([width, height])
  .thresholds([95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140]);

const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
  .style("fill", "#ccc");

g.selectAll(null)
  .data(contours(data.values))
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! It seems that the chart takes on the width and height of the size passed to it. How can I get it to fill the svg?